# Android Webview If No Internet Error Custom Page

Tags: webview, custom-error-pages

**Hi WebView for my application when there is no internet application opens and the site address is displayed for him when there is no internet error.I want to open the HML page, but even though I tried to help thank you.

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVo8A.png)

> java

```
    package com.app.xxxx;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
    import android.net.NetworkInfo;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.webkit.DownloadListener;
    import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
    import android.webkit.WebSettings;
    import android.webkit.WebView;
    import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
    import android.widget.ProgressBar;

    public class WebviewInits {

WebView webView;
SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
ProgressBar progressBar;
Context context;

public WebviewInits(WebView webView, SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout, ProgressBar progressBar,Context context) {
this.webView = webView;
this.swipeRefreshLayout = swipeRefreshLayout;
this.progressBar = progressBar;
this.context=context;
}

public void initWeb(){
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled( true );
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath("caches");
webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setSavePassword(true);
webView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
offlineLoad();//TODO Delete if you don't want offline load

webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uri);
context.startActivity(intent);
    }
});

swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
webView.loadUrl(webView.getUrl());
    }
});

webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
if (!swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing()){ //If you didn't refresh the page by using swiperefresh it will show progressbar.
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
if (url.startsWith("https://play.google.com/") || url.startsWith("http://play.google.com/")) {
    try {
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
Activity host = (Activity) view.getContext();
host.startActivity(intent);
return true;
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
// Google Play app is not installed, you may want to open the app store link
Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
view.loadUrl("https://play.google.com/store/apps/" + uri.getHost() + "?" + uri.getQuery());
return false;
    }
}
return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); //It will hide progressbar because our page loaded.
if (swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing()){
    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false); //This will hide swiperefresh icon if we refreshed.
}
super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }
});webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
}
//TODO Offline Cache Load
public void offlineLoad(){
webView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize( 5 * 1024 * 1024 ); // 5MB Size of storage that it will take
webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath( context.getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath() );
webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess( true );
webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled( true );
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT ); // load online by default

if ( !WebviewInits.isNetworkAvailable(context) ) { // loading offline
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK );
}
} 
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
// if no network is available networkInfo will be null
// otherwise check if we are connected
if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
    return true;
}
return false;
}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle error in WebView,
You should override onReceivedError according to the following code,

```
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
.
.
.

   // api<23
   @Override
   public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String url) {
        view.stopLoading();
        webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error/error.html"); // load error page from asset folder

// handle error

    }

  // api> 23
  @Override
  @TargetApi(android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) 
  public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
    view.stopLoading();
    webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error/error.html"); // load error page from asset folder

// handle error

//          super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
  }
.
.
.

}
```

also, you can check the connection in shouldOverrideUrlLoading, and if is not connected load error page, try this :

```
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {


            if (!isNetworkAvailable(getApplicationContext())) {
                showCustomErrorPage();
                return true;
            }
.
.
.

}
```

showCustomErrorPage function :

```
private void showCustomErrorPage() {

   webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error/error.html");

}
```